# nest a UIView into another UIView in storyboard without lossing contents layout

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview

In Xcode 5, using storyboards:

- Take a UIView , `viewA`
- Make it the full size of the screen
- Fill it with buttons and images
- Make a second UIView, `viewB`
- Take `viewA` and nest it inside `viewB` (drag and drop)

It will nest, but all of the objects in `viewA` get moved to a pile in the center of the view.

I know that I can nest them first then do my layout. It also occurs to me that one could leave them as is then add `viewA` as a subview of `viewB` in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, or similar.

**However, Is there a way to nest  the views in the storyboard without loosing the original layout of `viewA`**

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are describing here. Xcode 5.0.2. Nesting UIViews works fine.

Comment: As a suggestion try dragging the UIView in the Document Outline panel.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think this was just some weird fluke. I restarted my Mac and it is nesting the views properly now.

Comment: I always used to have this problem, but now I can't seem to recreate it when trying! My guess is it's not an issue in Xcode 5 now.